# Parameter is not valid when loading Image from MySql to PictureBox2 in C# winform Application

Tags: c#, mysql

Please help me with this as I have tried so many solutions suggested from multiple sources.
I have a pictureBox2 with a show button below it. The idea is, if I click the show button, the JPEG Image will appear in the pictureBox2 from my `MySql` DB. The image is in a blob field within a table called Recipy(Pardon my incorrects spelling for recipe). This is my code:

```
MySqlCommand comm;
MySqlDataReader rdr;
MySqlDataAdapter da;

string Query = "select image from chefassist.recipy where name ='" + textBox1.Text + "';";   
MySqlConnection connectToD = new MySqlConnection("server = localhost; database = chefassist; uid 
     = root; pwd = n0clu387;");
comm = new MySqlCommand(Query, connectToD);
da = new MySqlDataAdapter(comm);

try
{
    connectToD.Open();
   
    rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();
     while(rdr.Read())
    {
        //string sName = rdr.GetString("name");
        //textBox1.Text = sName;
        byte[] imgg = (byte[])(rdr["image"]);
        if (imgg == null)
        {
            pictureBox2.Image = null;
        }
        else
        {
            MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(imgg);
            pictureBox2.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mstream);
        }
    }

catch (Exception ex)
                {
    
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
```

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to SQL injections. Consider using [parameterized queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_Parameters.htm)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use parameters in your SQL Query

```
  string Query = "select image from chefassist.recipy where name = @Param;   
 

 using( MySqlConnection connectToD = new MySqlConnection("server = localhost; database = chefassist; uid = root; pwd = n0clu387;"))
 {

  using( comm = new MySqlCommand(Query, connectToD))
  {
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param", textBox1.Text); --More secure like this.

    //da = new MySqlDataReader(comm); --I didn't understand why you need this. Use 
    DataReader instead, your code below seems using a datareader.

    try
    {
     connectToD.Open();
     
     //If you are sure that the query will return only one image, you can use 
     // byte[] buffer = (byte[])(comm.ExecuteScalar());


     //If you want to use a reader

     var rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();
     while(rdr.Read())
     {
       
       //string sName = rdr.GetString("name");
       //textBox1.Text = sName;
       byte[] buffer = (byte[])(rdr["image"]);
       if (imgg == null)
       {
         pictureBox2.Image = null;
       }
       else
       {
         pictureBox2.Image = ByteArrayToImage(buffer);
       }
     }
    }
  }
 }

 catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
```

You can try this method to convert your byte array yo image

```
 public Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] buffer)
 {
   var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
   Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
   return returnImage;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.I get this error message saying cannot convert byte[] to system.io.stream. Any Ideas?

Comment: Which line throw the error ? this one : var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer); ?

Comment: pictureBox2.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imgg);

Comment: Right, sorry, I changed the code. In fact, you should replace it by pictureBox2.Image = ByteArrayToImage(buffer);

Comment: I apologise for being a pain but i still get paramer invalid

Comment: Don't worry :) So, you have your byte array correctly initiated. And can you trace your code step by step and tell me which line exactly throws this error ? In the ByteArrayToImage method ? Or before ?

Comment: Thank you. So if i put a line breaker in my code,i see no errors. I reads the line that says  pictureBox2.Image = ByteArrayToImage(imgg); in my try block and then it goes to the catch block and  a messagebox says Parameters is not valid.

Comment: I believe that your byte  array is not bytes of an image. How it is saved into the blob field ? Can you post the content of the field  at the end of your question ?

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for Saving the image to my mySql data base. I use MySqlWorkbench:

```
try
            {
                OpenFileDialog opn = new OpenFileDialog();
                opn.Filter = "Choose Image(*.jpg; *.png; *.jpeg)|*.jpg; *.png; *.jpeg";
                if (opn.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(opn.FileName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            MySqlCommand comm;
            MySqlDataReader rdr;

            //string Query = "UPDATE `chefassist`.`recipy` SET image = '@Img' WHERE name='Herb and Lemon Soup'";
            string Query = "UPDATE `chefassist`.`recipy` image=@img where name='" + this.textBox1.Text + "';";
            MySqlConnection connectToD = new MySqlConnection("server = localhost; database = chefassist; uid = root; pwd = n0clu387;");
            comm = new MySqlCommand(Query, connectToD);
            connectToD.Open();

            try
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
                byte[] img = ms.ToArray();
                MySqlCommand cmd;
                //String qry = "UPDATE `chefassist`.`recipy` SET image = '@Img' WHERE name = 'Herb and Lemon Soup'";
                string qry = "UPDATE `chefassist`.`recipy` SET image=@img where name='" + this.textBox1.Text + "';";
                comm = new MySqlCommand(qry, connectToD);
                //comm.Parameters.Add("@Id", MySqlDbType.Int32);
                comm.Parameters.Add("@img", MySqlDbType.MediumBlob);
                //comm.Parameters["@Id"].Value = txtAddress.Text;
                comm.Parameters["@img"].Value = img;
                if (comm.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
```

This is my function for Saving ByteArrayToImage:

```
public Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] buffer)
        {

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
            Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
            return returnImage;
        }
```

Finally, this is my current code in my show button:

```
MySqlCommand comm;
            
            //MySqlDataReader rdr;
            //MySqlDataAdapter da;

            string Query = "select image from chefassist.recipy where image = @img";

            using (MySqlConnection connectToD = new MySqlConnection("server = localhost; database = chefassist; uid = root; pwd = n0clu387;"))
            {
                using (comm = new MySqlCommand(Query, connectToD))
                {
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img",textBox1.Text);
                    connectToD.Close();
                    try
                    {
                        connectToD.Open();
                        var rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();

                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            byte[] imgg = (byte[])(rdr["image"]);
                            
                            if (imgg == null)
                            {
                                pictureBox2.Image = null;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //pictureBox2.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imgg);
                                pictureBox2.Image = ByteArrayToImage(imgg);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```